# only id(String), alias(Provider), or alias(ProviderConvertible) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

only id(String), alias(Provider), or alias( Provider Convertible) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

Comment: plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
in build.gradle(:app), in the plugins{} block put this code

```
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

then in the build.gradle project level

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false
```